# unity-contol-center makes Xorg CPU usage at 100% on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xorg, cpu-load, unity-control-center

This is the issue:
randomly my PC start to lag and `top` shows a 100% usage for Xorg.
Now, I know that it couldn' be Xorg itself the problem but a call from a client. So I killed everything, one by one, finding that it's unity-control-center's fault even if its window is not open.
so i did

> killall unity-control-center

and after a while it comes again like magic!

Here's my specs:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

CPU:  Intel Core i7-4790
GPU:  GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
RAM:  8GB (7.7 GiB)

Tell me if you need more info. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any findings here? This happens to me with the surface dock, when using a second screen. Killing it CPU goes to normal.

Comment: nothing for now. :-|